# Hibernate SQL - intermediate table b/w parent and child (of different types)

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, hibernate

I'm working on a program to store patient data.

- I have a `patient` table.
- An intermediate table `patient_disease` to map the patient with the disease(s) they have (storing Ids and table name of the disease).
- I have many `disease____` tables, each with their respective columns/data.
- `patient` maintains a 1:M relation with `patient_disease`
- `patient_disease` maintains a 1:1 relation with `disease____`

How it works right now is that the `patient` and the `disease____` are saved and then their generated Ids are stored in `patient_disease` along with the table name of the disease.

1. Is this the right way to go about this?
2. I'm using hibernate to load these relations. Loading list of `patient_disease` is no problem but how do I load the disease object when the table name of the disease is stored in `patient_disease` object itself? (secondarytable maybe?)

I'm sorry if this sounds confusing

[image]

Comment: I remove the tags , please tag only the rdbms you are using

Comment: I am using both of the tags you want to remove..

Comment: You use `MS SQL Server` and also `MySQL`?

Comment: yes I do. can you help?

Comment: Well can we see your shcema?

Comment: added a simplified schema

Comment: From your shcema `patient` have one or more `disease_template` , and `disease_template` have one or more `patient` . **many to many**

Comment: `patient` 1:M with `patient_disease`
and `patient_disease` 1:1 with `disease_template`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144171/discussion-between-sami-and-aashir).

Answer (score 0):

In your case , you need to create two more tables.

The 1st table whish containe :

- ID_Des (PK)
- Desease

And the 2nd table:

- ID_Patient (PK , FK) (reference to Patient_ID)
- ID_Des (PK , FK) (reference to ID_des)

[image]